# Kohana 3.2 select issue

Tags: mysql, ajax, kohana

I have table with 'servers' name in my db. So when I want to add there some data with that code it's just ok:

```
    public function action_add()
    {
        $serverGameId = (int)Arr::get($_POST, 'serverGameId', '');
        $newServerName = Arr::get($_POST, 'newServerName', '');

        try
        {
           $server = new Model_Server();
           $server->Name = $newServerName;
           $server->GameId = $serverGameId;
           $server->save();
        }
        catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
        {
           echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => $e->errors('validation')));
           return false;
        }

        $this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "serverId" => $server->Id));
        return true;
    }
```

Here is a model:

```
class Model_Server extends ORM {

protected $_table_name = 'servers';

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        'Name' => array(
            array('not_empty'),
        )
    );
}
```

}

But I have problem when I try to select it from the table:

```
    public function action_servers()
{
        $gameId = (int)Arr::get($_POST, 'gameId', '');

        if($gameId == -1) return false;

        try
        {
            $servers = ORM::factory('server')
                        ->where('GameId', '=', $gameId)
                        ->find_all();
        }
        catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
        {
           echo json_encode(array("success" => false, "errors" => $e->errors('validation')));
           return false;
        }

        $this->request->headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        echo json_encode(array("success" => true, "servers" => $servers, "gameId" => $gameId));
        return true;
    }
```

I already try to solve problem with change code inside of try block on:

```
$servers = DB::select('servers')->where('GameId', '=', $gameId);
```

Even when I try just get all my servers from db without '->where' it's doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `print_r($servers);` inside `try` block to see what you get from model.

And `$servers` is some class with results - use foreach to get result (one by one)

```
$results = array();

foreach($servers as $row) {
   //echo $row->Name;
   $results[] = $row->Name;
}
```

Or

```
$results = array();

foreach($servers as $row) {
   //echo $row->as_array();
   $results[] = $row->as_array();
}
```